# How to check a used linux device (reMarkable) for malitious files?

Tags: linux, security

I just obtained a used reMarkable 2, which runs Linux. It's an open platform, so you easily can put new software onto the device via SSH.

Now I'm wondering how I would go about checking whether the previous owner installed a keylogger or the like.

The device's factory reset will only re-install system files and wipe the dedicated storage location, but not delete user added system files.

I already tried checking `ps` output for processes that shouldn't run, but is there another way? Is it advisable to run a simple virus scan? Would it find simple bash scripts the owner created, if they do harmful things? Can the device's OS run inside a virtual machine without the scanner noticing? Does that depend on the processor's VM capacities?

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably a good idea to not input sensitive data into such machines, no matter how thorough your scans are.

Comment: aw man, the rM2 has its own brand of spyware. I was given one. in an hour i found where the things spies on users, stores unencrypted passwords, ... 
anyway trying to detect the malware might be kinda pointless, what you can do is reflash it with yocto. its what the oem uses. oh, and there is a lot of stuff they should have scrubbed before releasing the OS. Its running a modified version of CoreOS, Im not sure where you can find an actual distribution.